# Turn off scientific notation for interger (2^20)

Tags: c++, output, scientific-notation

When I print pow(2, 20), the output is: 1.04858e+06

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << pow(2, 20) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I turn the output back to 1048576?

Comment: Why don't you simply use an unsigned integer `(2u << 20)`?

Comment: Have a look at `std::fixed`. But seriously... A power of 2 with `pow()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Shouldn't it be `(1u << 20)`? It should: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ace4199fbde6a563). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat oops, yes of course :-)

Comment: The problem here is that you're not passing a expression of an integral type to the `<<` operator, but `double`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: `pow(2,20)` is not an integer. `pow` is not for integers, its for floating point numbers. `2 << 20` is an integer.